# Yii / Gii : must extend from CModel

Tags: php, yii

When I try to generate a FORM from GII 
the following error arise :

```
'application.models.Driectory' must extend from CModel.
```

although the model :

```
class Directory extends CModel
{
  ..
}
```

**Update**

When I rename the model everything work !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you didn't mean Directory? Directory might be a reserved word in PHP?